# Select the first column name where a value is null by Id

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, select

I would like to get the first null-valued column **name** when selecting by Id:

I tried:

```
SELECT Snap1,Snap2,Snap3,Snap4
where NULL
FROM tbtProgressSnap
where Id=3

Id | Snap1 | Snap2 | Snap3 | Snap4|
-----------------------------------
1  |       |       |/a.png |/b.png|
-----------------------------------
2  | d.png | m.png |       |      |
-----------------------------------
3  | g.png |l.png  |p.png  |      |
```

I expect to get, with respective `Id`s

```
1 Snap1
2 Snap3
3 Snap4
```

Comment: What if there are 5 'snaps'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT WorkId, 
      (CASE WHEN Snap1 IS NULL OR snap1 = '' THEN 'Snap1'
            WHEN Snap2 IS NULL OR snap2 = '' THEN 'Snap2'
            WHEN Snap3 IS NULL OR snap3 = '' THEN 'Snap3'
            WHEN Snap4 IS NULL OR snap4 = '' THEN 'Snap4'
            WHEN Snap5 IS NULL OR snap5 = '' THEN 'Snap5'
            ELSE ''
       END) AS snapValue
FROM tbtProgressSnap 
WHERE WorkId=4;
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DMEO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2981c7/3)

**OUTPUT**

```
| WORKID | SNAPVALUE |
|--------|-----------|
|      4 |     Snap5 |
```

Comment: sorry :get with Id like where Id

Comment: get first null column with Id like where Id=1 Answer :- Snap1

Comment: What happens when there's 60 columns? Are you going to expand that case statement for each column? There's a smarter way to do this which involves querying for the column names themselves, then specifying them dynamically in your query. I'm not at my dev machine to test right now but will come back tomorrow.

Comment: no any kind of WorkId in table its write by mistake. just get first null column name with Id only

Comment: @SaharshShah forget about workid there is no any workId

Comment: just get a first null column name with Id

Comment: but how i get the result for Id=3 and result is "Snap4"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66457/discussion-between-sandeep-singh-and-saharsh-shah).

Answer (score 1):

You need a case with a group by over min():

```
SELECT
    min(id) id, 
    CASE
        WHEN Snap1 IS NULL THEN 'Snap1'
        WHEN Snap2 IS NULL THEN 'Snap2'
        WHEN Snap3 IS NULL THEN 'Snap3'
        WHEN Snap4 IS NULL THEN 'Snap4'
    END snap
FROM tbtProgressSnap 
WHERE Snap1 IS NULL OR Snap2 IS NULL OR Snap3 IS NULL OR Snap4 IS NULL 
GROUP BY 2
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/902bd/1) with your sample data producing your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a builtin function but you can always do this:

```
SELECT Id,
CASE
    WHEN Snap1 IS NULL THEN 'Snap1'
    WHEN Snap2 IS NULL THEN 'Snap2'
    WHEN Snap3 IS NULL THEN 'Snap3'
    WHEN Snap4 IS NULL THEN 'Snap4'
END AS FirstNullColumnName,
CASE
    WHEN Snap1 IS NULL THEN Snap1
    WHEN Snap2 IS NULL THEN Snap2
    WHEN Snap3 IS NULL THEN Snap3
    WHEN Snap4 IS NULL THEN Snap4
END AS FirstNullColumnValue
FROM tbtProgressSnap
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Snap1,Snap2,Snap3,Snap4 from tbtProgressSnap where snap1 =""
```